# How to recreate the shimmering effect in ks by ARTHECRIS?

Tags: geometry-dash

Geometry Dash 2.2 recently was released. Included in this update were a bunch of new triggers, including triggers that can affect how the screen works.

I was recently playing a level called "ks" by ARTHECRIS. This level basically spams screen effects, but it's still a good level.

Starting at around 18%, the level has this really cool shimmering effect (or whatever it's called) as seen here:

[image]

<sub>Screenshot taken at around 18.5%</sub>

While I am already pretty familiar with new triggers introduced in 2.2, I have not been able to recreate this screen effect in the editor.

So my question is, how can I recreate this effect using the new triggers introduced in 2.2?

I feel like this might have something to do with the "Mode"/"UI" trigger, or maybe the "(↑)" trigger (Setup Keyframe 0) but I'm not sure how I would use that to create the effect.

I also sadly cannot copy the level to see how it works since it's protected by a 4-6 digit password that hasn't been figured out yet.

<sub>* Note: The reason I say "4-6" digit long password is because if you want to allow a level to be copied (but only by certain people), you can protect it using a 4-6 digit long password. This is difficult to figure out with a total of 111000 possible combinations for a password.
* Less needed, but still needed note: Also 2.2 pretty much breaks all of Megahack for Geometry Dash (including Copy Hack), meaning that even if I had Megahack, that's only working up until the last 2.1 version of GD, so I wouldn't be able to just copy the level using that.</sub>

Comment: sorry, I just realized that I meant "shimmering effect". I will fix this.